# Date time parsing in Java

Tags: java, date, timezone

Given this code...

```
 String date = "11:00 AM";

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern")); // --> should be GMT-4

 TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

 Date parse = sdf.parse(date); // -- gives Thu Jan 01 16:00:00 GMT 1970
```

Why does date parsing give me 16:00 and not 15:00?

Comment: EST 11:00 AM is a 16:00 in GMT. So output is correct, More info here: http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.in/to/est/index.htm

Comment: that's cuz `US/Eastern` is `GMT-5` and not `GMT-4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `java.util.Date` to store time only. It will assign the 1970 year, which in some cases is incorrect. I would recommend to use `org.joda.time.LocalTime` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Take day light savings also into consideration. This should give you what you expect

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST5EDT"));

Answer (score 0):

If you are not providing any date portion by default it will be assigned the default `Epoche standard date(01 Jan 1970 00:00 Hours` is called `Epoche standard time` and it is taken as standard to measure all the time related calculations as base time).

The `getTime()` method of java.util.Date class returns the total number of milliseconds between the given `date(including time also)` and `Epoche standard( 01 Jan 1970 00:00 Hours)`.
Though you are not using `getTime()` method so it is irrelevant here.
So simply you are getting that time.
And according to GMT it is right.

I thinks it will help you.